# Selecting Distinct Rows Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently returning a list using the following

```
Test.GetPrevList(Current.Id, UserId);
```

This list has 5 columns
`User ID`
`First Name`
`Last Name`
`Department`
`Week`

What I noticed is that if an employee switched departments they will show up twice on the list.

What I want to do is select the most recent record based on the most recent week column, using Linq as the stored procedure is used multiple times.

Comment: More Code Please. Exact structure please. `"List has 4 Columns"`. What is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order users by week, then group them by Id and select the first user in each group:

```
var userList = Test.GetPrevList(Current.Id, UserId);
var users = userList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Week)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
                    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

use a simple LINQ call too `Distinct()`

Distinct can be used also with `IEqualityComparer`, like

```
IEnumerable<User> users =  users.Distinct(new UserComparer());
```

where `UserComparer` a class that implements some custom comparison logic.

Comment: This won't help select the latest record.